# Matlab: Why does subtracting a positive number from a negative number not result in significant roundoff error when they are both very close to 0?

Tags: matlab

I am using matlab online to subtract a negative number very close to 0, from a positive number very close to 0, and am wondering why this doesn't result in significant roundoff error? Is matlab doing some kind of optimisation to use addition instead of subtraction?

Comment: Please explain why you expect a larger error than you get. Also read [mre], an actual example of what you did, what you got, and what you expected to get might clarify what you are asking. Note that addition and subtraction are exactly the same operation for floating-point numbers. There's just a sign bit difference.

Comment: @acelito For the specific case you cite, where p is positive and n is negative, p-n is the equivalent of p+(-n) where you are adding two positive numbers. You will get what you get depending on the relative magnitudes of the numbers involved. Are you perhaps confusing this with *cancellation* error that might result from subtracting two same-signed numbers that are roughly the same in magnitude, such as the calculation p1-p2 where p1 and p2 are both positive?

Answer (score 0):

Numerical cancellation is a consequence of using floating point arithmetics and in that sense unrelated to the specific programming language being used. Matlab is thus also affected.

The code below shows the round-off error in a particular Matlab example. It calculates the finite difference approximation for the derivative of `exp(x)-1` at the point `x=0`. The symmetric difference quotient requires `exp(+epsilon)-1` and `exp(-epsilon)-1` thereby reproducing the subtraction of a slightly positive and slightly negative number. The absolute approximation error is clearly behaving erratic for small `epsilon`. This is the round-off error. The effect increases as epsilon is getting smaller (read: the values get closer together).

[image]

I can imagine two reasons as to why you did not observe the numerical round-off error.

1. The round-off error is quite small and might remain unobserved in practice.
2. There are specific situations in which rounding errors exactly cancel. For example, you might modify this code to compute the derivative of `x^2` at `x=0`. However, the same rounding errors occur when calculating (-epsilon)^2 and (+epsilon)^2 and the numerical derivate works out just fine.

I hope this helps.

```
EpsilonList = logspace(-12,-2);

MyFunction = @(x) exp(x)-1;
TrueDerrivative = 1; % Derivative of exp(x)-1, exp(x), evaluated at x=0

% Initialize ErrorList
ErrorList = NaN(length(EpsilonList), 1);

%--- Compute ---%
for iter = 1:length(EpsilonList)
    
    % Increment
    epsilon = EpsilonList(iter);

    % Forward difference approximation
    FiniteDiffApprox = ( MyFunction(epsilon) - MyFunction(-epsilon) ) / (2*epsilon);

    % Approximation error
    DiffApproxError = FiniteDiffApprox - TrueDerrivative;

    % Store
    ErrorList(iter) = DiffApproxError;
end

%--- Create plot ---%
loglog(EpsilonList, abs(ErrorList), 'LineWidth', 3)
xlabel('epsilon', 'FontSize', 20)
ylabel('Absolute approximation error', 'FontSize', 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers, in case of matlab, `double` by default, are represented by 3 parts: a sign bit (positive/negative), an exponent (11 bits, 1 for sign) and a fraction (52 bits), see the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

The value represented by doubles is

```
(-1)^{sign} * 1.{fraction} * 2^{exponent}
```

or

```
(-1)^{sign} * 0.{fraction} * 2^{exponent}
```

where `{fraction}` is the floating point part of the middle number. In the first case, two numbers with a `{fraction}` part of 0 (so a middle number of 1) will differ at least `2^{-52}`. That is the value of `eps` in Matlab.

In the second case where the fraction also represents a very small number, the difference between two numbers can differ as little as `2^{-52} * 2^{-1022}`.